# Execute jquery command from a string without using eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I have this javascript array of jquery commands:

```
var a = ["$('div').hide();","$('span').show();","$('p').fadeIn(100);"];
```

I want to execute, let's say the first command in the array, but with no use of

```
eval(a[0]);
```

Is there a better possible way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Why have it in a string to start?

Comment: does `new Function(a[0])()` works for you!!! - (it is the same as using eval :()

Comment: @ArunPJohny — That is, effectively, `eval` by another name.

Comment: @Quentin that is why the `!!!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your precondition: no.

The better solution would be to change the array so it contained functions instead of strings.

```
var a = [
    function () {
        $('div').hide();
    },
    function () {
        $('span').show();
    },
    function () {
        $('p').fadeIn(100);
    }
];

a[0]();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an object with functions in it

```
var a = {
    hideDiv: function () {
        $('div').hide();
    },
    showSpan: function () {
        $('span').show();
    },
    fadeinP: function () {
        $('p').fadeIn(100);
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
a.hideDiv();
a.showSpan();
a.fadeinP();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fg8jq6ya/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Not an especially *better* way to do so, but a different way:

```
// create a new script element
var elem = document.createElement("script");
elem.type = "text/javascript";
elem.innerHTML = a[0];

// add it to the document body so it gets executed
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(elem);
```

However, if you can choose to have a different data structure to start with and have functions instead of their source code, it becomes much easier and cleaner:

```
var a = [
    function() { $('div').hide(); },
    function() { $('span').show(); }
    function() { $('p').fadeIn(100); }];
// invokation is clean
a[0]();
```

Comment: Is the first option really better than using eval()?, is'nt it the same after all?

Comment: That's exactly why I said it's different but not *better*, yes it's basically an `eval`.